# Link to pages/home not rendering the way I expect

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I created a link to my homepage in my navbar that when clicked goes to the URL I want it to, but it is not rendering the view that I was expecting.

My pages controller has a home action and then in my home view I have a simple h1 tag that I am using just to test that the code is working.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end
end
```

The view I have for this is in the pages directory and I have a filed titled home.html.erb.

I then created the route for my home action.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  get "/pages/home", to: "pages#home"
end
```

This is what the link looks like it my navbar

```
<%= link_to "Home", pages_home_path %>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link the text for home.html.erb does not show up, the text from show.html.erb is what is displayed.

Can someone lend some advice? I can provide more details if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your routes are colliding. When you do `resources :pages`, you have defined a few routes with that DSL.

Read about what `resources` does in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Your program thinks that `/pages/home` is actually `pages/(:id)` where `home` is being incorrectly mapped to the `:id` variable.

Try removing the `resources :pages` line from your routes file.

If you do want some `pages` functionality, use the `only` keyword.

`resources :pages, only: [:index]`

Comment: Thanks yes. Makes perfect sense.